# Display Popup in magento admin Dashboard

Tags: admin, adminhtml, popup, adminnotification

As you all are aware of, Magento shows a popup on the new version release if the current magento version is below the latest version.

I want to develop a similar type of popup as soon as user logs in into the admin panel.

Answer (score 3):

The notifications, like *"Magento 1.9.1 is now available"* come from this RSS feed: http://notifications.magentocommerce.com/community/notifications.rss

It is processed by `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed`. Many extensions add their own notification feed by extending this class and overriding `getFeedUrl()` and calling `checkUpdate()` periodically using a cronjob or on each login using an observer.

Besides that, you can also dynamically add notifications using

```
Mage::getModel('adminnotification/inbox')->addNotice("title", "text");
```

Besides `addNotice` there is also:

- `addCritical()`
- `addMajor()`
- `addMinor()`

for warnings of different severity.

Comment: +1 thanks for this wonderful answer. would you mind to explain how this rss popup box get triggered ? I inspected `DashboardController` and layouts and couldn't find relevant block!!

Comment: Check `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminnotification.xml`